# Is there anyway to have Dynamic Controller in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP coding and I need to know is there anyway to have a dynamic controller name(not controller function name) in Codeigniter.

I am having around 5 Controllers like Sf_client.php, Sf_network.php, Sf_display.php etc... and coding are same in all these 5 controllers except one variable name which is different.

```
 <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Sf_client extends UTF_Controller
    {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->resource_subtype = "client";
        }

        public function list() {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Client list';
            $this->template->set_title('CTL - '.$data['page_title']);
            $this->template->build('resources/list',$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

Other Controllers are similar to the above except the `$this->resource_subtype = "client"`, it will be like "network", "display" etc...

Now the url is like, http://localhost/Sf_client/, http://localhost/Sf_network/ etc...

Is there anyway to have one Controller file and passing the variable name ? So that I can eliminate the duplicate Controller files.

I am having other Controllers as well. So, i need something like if it matches "sf" in the url.

Any help will be most appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dynamic `controllers` is not possible because even if you name the `class` dynamically, you still would have to have a file of the same name. That's how `CI`'s `URL` work.

> **What you could do, however, is that configure the routing so that when
>   you hit a certain `URL` it corresponds to another `controller`, then
>   in that `controller` you can check the `URL` and assign desired value
>   to the variable accordingly.**

I created a demo for your problem and this ↓ worked for me. See, if it works for you as well.

**routes.php**

```
$route['default']    = 'Sf_client'; // say default is 'Sf_client' -- you can ignore it if you already have a default. We'll be creating only this controller.
$route['Sf_network'] = 'Sf_client'; // route requests to this controller
$route['Sf_display'] = 'Sf_client'; // ...
```

**view**

```
<a href="<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>">Sf_client</a> <!-- OR base_url('Sf_client'); // if not default -->
<a href="<?PHP echo base_url('Sf_network'); ?>">Sf_network</a> <!-- will correspond to Sf_client but the URL won't change -->
<a href="<?PHP echo base_url('Sf_display'); ?>">Sf_display</a> <!-- ... -->
```

**Sf_client.php(controller)**

```
class Sf_client extends UTF_Controller{

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $segment = $this->uri->segment(1); // get the first segment from the URL which is controller's name

        switch($segment){ // check the segment value

            case 'Sf_network': 
                $this->resource_subtype = 'network';
                break;

            case 'Sf_display': 
                $this->resource_subtype = 'display';
                break;

            // ignore if default ↓↓
            /* case 'Sf_client': 
                $this->resource_subtype = 'client';
                break; */

            default: 
                $this->resource_subtype = 'client';
        }
        echo $this->resource_subtype; // will return network if in http://localhost/Sf_network 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
public function mytest($controller = 'home', $method = 'index', $slug = false)
{
    //uri(3) -> controller
    //uri(4) -> method
    //uri(5) -> slug
    $begin_uri_count = 3;
    
    $controller = (is_null($this->uri->segment($begin_uri_count))?$controller:$this->uri->segment($begin_uri_count));
    $method = (is_null($this->uri->segment($begin_uri_count+1))?$method:$this->uri->segment($begin_uri_count+1));
    $slug = $this->uri->segment($begin_uri_count+2);
    
    if( !$slug OR is_null($slug) )
    {
        $slug = 'overview';
    }
    
    echo 'C = '.$controller.' / M = '.$method.' / S = '.$slug;
}
```

Then you can check the correct Controller/Method name via a whitelist if you like.